# How do I apply both bold and center in python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I'm using python-docx to put a text into MS Word. I can make it bold or center,but how to do both.
Here's the bold:

```
p=document.add_paragraph().add_run('test word')
p.font.size = Pt(16)
p.bold = True
```

Here's the center:

```
p=document.add_paragraph('test word')
p.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

how to do both bold and center?

Comment: I wrote a more elaborate answer I think can help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate between `paragraph` and `run` and define each:

```
p=document.add_paragraph()
p.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
r=p.add_run('test word')
r.font.size = Pt(16)
r.bold = True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `p` as the reference of this paragraph, and then use `add_run()` to add your text. Just like this:

```
p = document.add_paragraph()
p.add_run('test word').bold = True
p.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
```

Sorry, I can't upload my picture, but I have tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I have in a project created a helper-class that I call `Text`. We also add a function that adds the text to the document.

Now we can do this:

```
add_Text([Text("NORMAL TEXT "),Text("BOLD TEXT",bold=True)]
```

The function will make sure the runs are in the same paragraph. As the center paragraph is a property of the paragraph I added it outside:

```
add_Text([Text("NORMAL TEXT "),Text("BOLD TEXT",bold=True), align='center']
```

Here is a full example of what I mean:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH

class Text:
    def __init__(self, text, bold=False, italic=False):
        self.text = text
        self.bold = bold
        self.italic = italic

def add_text(textitems, align=False):
    p = document.add_paragraph('')
    if align == 'center':
        p.paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
    for t in textitems:
        r = p.add_run(t.text)
        if t.bold:
            r.bold = True
        if t.italic:
            r.italic = True

document = Document()
document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

add_text([
    Text('Text ', bold=True, italic=True),
    Text('Text2', bold=False, italic=True)
    ], align='center')

add_text([
    Text('Text ', bold=True, italic=True),
    Text('Text2', bold=False, italic=True)
    ])

document.save('demo.docx')
```